# c# express built solution with firebird database has an error when run

Tags: c#, error-handling, installation, exe, firebird2.5

[image]
I've been I'm trying to create an exe file of my application in c# express. My problem is when I run the application.exe after I build from release it shows me an error

```
System.ArgumentException: An invalid connection string argument has been supplied or a required connection string argument has not been supplied.
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionString.Validate()
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
at Mis_Service.Loginfrm.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\c sharp projects\samples\Mis-Service\Mis-Service\Loginfrm.cs:line 31
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I think the error only occurs when I connect to the database firebird. I am using the reference as follows.

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
```

When I try to run the program using the start button of c# express the code works fine. Is there something that i missed? I want to make the my application in exe so that i can create an installer using 3rd party software

here is my code in app.config

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
  <add key="ProviderName" value="MSDASQL.1"/>
  <add key="SecurityInfo" value="False"/>
  <add key="Driver" value="Firebird/InterBase(r) driver"/>
  <add key="UserID" value="sysdba"/>
  <add key="Password" value="masterkey"/>
  <add key="Database" value="D:\\database\\DB_GENERAL.FDB"/>
  <add key="DataSource" value="localhost"/>
    </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

in my class

```
conProvider = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProviderName"]; // sample on how i call app.config to string
conString = "Provider=" + conProvider + ";" +
            "Persist Security Info=" + conSecurityInfo + ";" +
            "Driver=" + conDriver + ";" +
            "User ID=" + conUserID + ";" +
            "Password=" + conPassword + ";" +
            "Database=" + conDatabase + ";" +
            "DataSource=" + conDataSource + ";" +
            "Charset=NONE;";
```

Comment: Whats your connection string, and how are you supplying it?

Comment: And the release build has all these in the app.config file that it can access, from where you are running it. i.e. they are all not only in a debug config file, or you didn't just copy the release .exe somewhere else, without its config file?. Are you able to also show the code you 'assemble' the connection string with

Comment: The connection string looks like IBPhoenix ODBC Connection Driver. But you are including the Firebird ADO.NET data Provider via using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient; I would have though a connection string more like User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=SampleDatabase.fdb;DataSource=localhost;
Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;
MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0; would be more appropriate. Do you initialize a FBConnection object?

Comment: ok I'll try that connections string although my code is working fine when build in debug mode.

Comment: And Not good practice to concatenate strings to build connection strings, use a ConnectionStringBuilder, in this case FbConnectionStringBuilder

Comment: Also, Website that I find helpful with connection string issues, [connectionstring.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. Weirdly enough it is now working. These are what I did.

1. I changed my connection string based on https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/ posted by Ojay
2. I copied the app.config file to my release folder
3. Weirdly enough my antivirus (norton) is blocking my processes when I'm trying to build my exe so I disabled my anti virus temporarily.